# Recording WebRTC video chat (on vLine)

Tags: webrtc, vline

I am using [vLine](https://vline.com/) as WebRTC chat service.
I would like to record the chat window and put it on server.
How can I do that?
Generally speaking ,is it possible on WebRTC?

I am using chrome v28.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try recording it on the client side via something like [RecordRTC](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/RecordRTC/).

Recording a MediaStream will be a [standard feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/) available with the WebRTC APIs, but it has not yet been implemented: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-media-capture/2013Jul/0049.html

We plan on adding support for recording to our API as well. Feel free to vote for it on our [UserVoice page](https://vline.uservoice.com/forums/183120-general/suggestions/4135037-allow-recording) and add any comments on how you think it should work.

Comment: RecordRTC is useless, no need to go for it. clean HTML5 APIs available , better to use them. demos showing single stream recording, not conference record.